# Convert Date and Time into a Single string Timestamp in seconds

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datetime, timestamp

I am developing an Android app which allows user to set the date and time for a timer function.
I would like to store the set date and time data into a single line timestamp in seconds.
Example:

```
String datetime = Integer.toString(mDay) + Integer.toString(mMonth) + Integer.toString(mYear) + Integer.toString(mHour) + Integer.toString(mMinute);
```

The datetime will have the value as 11720202330 (11/7/2020 23:30)
I want to store it as a timestamp value in s which is 1594510200 in Epoch timestamp.
Thanks.

Comment: Your datetime `String` has a really unfavorable format...

Comment: If 11 July is given as 11720202330 (for example), how will 1 December be given? Can we distinguish it from 11 February? And is that a string or an integer?

Answer (score 4):

We have a standard for storing date-time data textually: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). No need to invent new formats.

The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( year , month , day ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( hour , minute ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( zoneName ) ;  // Ex: "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

Parsing ISO 8601 string.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2020-07-12T03:30:00Z" ) ;
```

I recommend against storing a date-time value as a count of seconds or milliseconds. Use the ISO 8601 strings instead. But if you insist:

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = instant.getEpochSecond() ;
```

Example usage. [Run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ZtyX9d).

```
int year = 2020 ;
int month = 7 ;
int day = 11 ;
int hour = 23 ;
int minute = 30 ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2020-07-11T23:30-04:00[America/Montreal]

> instant.toString(): 2020-07-12T03:30:00Z

> secondsSinceEpoch: 1594524600

Write `2020-07-12T03:30:00Z` to storage.

Comment: I am yet to learn from you this much simplicity and effectiveness of presenting the answers.

Comment: My timepicker and datepicker will produce these variables: mHour mMinute mDay mMonth mYear
How do I save it as shown above??

Comment: @BrianHeu I added example usage.

Answer (score 0):

test it

```
   String str_date = "11/7/2020 23:31";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
    Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
    System.out.println("Today is " + date.getTime());
```

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Suggesting these legacy classes in 2020 is poor advice.

Comment: This code ignores the crucial issue of time zones. Results may vary at runtime.

Comment: I didn't think the date was right at all.
I just converted a static date to Unix Time.